# getSystemService() method is not recognized

Tags: android, listadapter

LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

I am using getSystemService() but, I am taking "The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type CustomAdapter" error

What to use instead of getSystemService or any other solution?

Answer (score 2):

you can make adapter like that

```
public CustomAdapter(YourActivtyName context) {

    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) YourEnclosingActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Comment: See, getSystemService method is a method of a Context. So, in your CustomAdapter you should get somehow your Activity's context. Try passing it in the constructor if your adapter is in a different file or is a nested static class.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)YourClassName.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

or :

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

where `context` is the object of `Context` class.